# finding maximum value of triangle length

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, optimization, maxima-minima

After learning the applications of derivatives in finding maximum and minimum values I tried to conjure my own example. Now, say we have a triangle with two legs of equal length; what value must the angle included between the two equal-lengthed legs be in order to produce the greatest opposite side? I first wrote down the opposite length as a function of the angle (call the length opposite our variable angle $c$, call the angle itself $x$ and call the legs of equal length $a$): $c(x)^2 = 2a^2 - 2a^2\cos x$. This is the relation known as the law of cosines. Since the magnitude of the angle repeats periodically every $360$ degrees, we can say that it varies between $0$ and $360$ degrees. Intuitively thinking I expect to get the angle at which the maximum length of $c$ is produced to be $180$ degrees. So then, as a function of the angle, $c(x) = (2a^2 - 2a^2\cos x)^{1\over2}$. This maximum value of $c$ should be found at either $x = 0$, or $x = 360$, or at which $c\prime(x)$ is equal to zero. Since I don't expect it to be at $x = 0$ or $x = 360$, I take the derivative of $c(x)$ which is $= $$1\over2$$(2a^2 - 2a^2\cos x)^{-1\over2}2a^2\sin x$. Equating this to zero, I aquire $\sin x = 0$. And sine is $0$ at exactly two angles within a $0$ to $360$ degree range. These angles are  $0$ and $180$, hence by trial we find that $0$ is a minimum value, and $180$ is a maximum. I only need confirmation if my reasoning was correct. If not, please explain why. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes it is correct and confirms a blattant fact on a graphical representation. Btw : a triangle with 2 sides having equal lengths is called **isosceles**.

Comment: I apologize, and am aware of how obvious the result is. However, owing to that I have only recently learned maxima and minima theory, it is good to confirm even the most obvious results before I move on to those more complicated. Btw : it's spelled **blatant**

Comment: My keyboard was set on another language; I have only realized that halfway through the text. I shall edit it.

Comment: I suggest try doing the same for an isosceles triangle where you try to maximize the area.

Comment: @MathematicianByMistake I do not know if any of you are being sarcastic, however, as a beginning student, those are really good excersizes for me. In fact I found that the area of an iscoseles triangle is maximized at $90$ degrees of an angle. I'm also maximizing parallelogram areas as a function of one of the angle

Comment: @Camelot823 Good job! Oh, I can be sarcastic all the time but that was a genuine suggestion...

Comment: Meanwhile, I have had a look at your profile : congratulations for your early mastering of calculus. I apologize if my comment was looking a little sarcastic. There are a lot of geometry-based "training examples" for maxima and minima. For example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1449563/305862).

Comment: Thank you much for the wonderful complements and suggestions, I do indeed enjoy confirming euclidean, geometry-based  facts, even the most simplest ones, and will indeed look into the suggestions.

Comment: Another [exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1575102/305862).